# Let $R$ be the set of all functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Is $R$ a ring? If so, is it commutative, and does it have an identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can someone please tell me how this looks. Thanks in advance!
$$(R,+)$$

Take $R(x)$ and $G(x) \in \mathbb{R}$
then, $R(x) + G(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $R$ is closed under addition.

Also, $0 + R(x) = R(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ is the identity,
and $R(x) + (-R(x)) = 0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is the additive inverse.

- $[R(x) + G(x)] + H(x) = R(x) + [G(x) + H(x)]$ implies $R$ is associative.
- $ R(x) + G(x) = G(x) + R(x)$ implies $R$ is commutative.

Hence, $R$ is an abelian group.

$$(R,\times)$$

Take $R(x) \times G(x) = G(x) \times R(x)$ implies $R$ is associative,
and $R(x) \times G(x) = R(x) \in \mathbb{R}$.
Hence, $R$ contains the identity $1(=G(x)) \in \mathbb{R}$.
Also, $R(x) \times G(x) = G(x) \times R(x) \in \mathbb{R}$ implies $R$ is commutative.

Then, $$R(x)[G(x) + H(x)] = R(x) \times G(x) + R(x) \times H(x)$$
and $$[G(x) + H(x)] \times R(x) = G(x) \times R(x) + H(x) \times R(x)$$

Hence, $R$ obeys the distributive laws, and therefore $R$ is a commutative ring with identity $1.$

Comment: All those words aren't math and should be outside the `$` math delimiters.

Comment: OK, thanks @Randall

Comment: You shouldn't use $R$ as the variable for the ring *and* as a variable for a function.  And you declare a function as let $G\in R$ and not as take $G(x)\in \mathbb R$.  And you should explicitely point out that $F(x) + G(x)$ is actually equal to some function. $H(x) = F(x) + G(x)$. As it is, it just looks like you are saying some statements about for real numbers for a specific $x \in \mathbb R$ and not some statements about actual *functions*.

Comment: Yep, I see what you're saying @fleablood

Comment: Which is just style points.... I think everything you said, if I can get past the style point is pretty good.  I'd say things like, for any $f,g\in R$ define $f+g$ as the function $f+g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ via $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ which $f(x),g(x)\in \mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ is closed under addition is a well defined real function. i.e. $R$ is closed under addition.  The function $i(x)=0$ is a real function in $R$ and $f+i:x\to f(x)+0\to f(x)$ and $i+f:x\to 0+f(x)\to f(x)$ so $i$ serves as the additive identity.... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A ring is a set with two operations that satisfy certain conditions. You've got a set. What are the operations?

Comment: Addition and multiplication

Comment: @user551155 That is true in any ring, so that is a cop-out. The question is *how do you add things in this ring? How do you multiply things in this ring*?